# How to fix expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char **` while using strcmp() in a function

Tags: c, if-statement, char, initialization, strcmp

It's supposed to be a function that finds the sum, difference etc of a two numbers depending on the  chosen operator but when I use `strcmp()` to check the chosen operator I get the error `expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char **'`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <string.h>

int calc(int ran1,int ran2,char op){
    if(strcmp(op, "+")==0){
        return ran1+ran2;
    }
    if(strcmp(op, "-")==0){
        return ran1-ran2;
    if(strcmp(op, "*")==0){
        return ran1*ran2;
    }
    if(strcmp(op, "/")==0){
        return ran1/ran2;
    }
    }
}
int main(){
    int ran1=25;
    int ran2=5;
    char op="+";
    printf("%d", calc(ran1, ran2, op));

}
```

Comment: You must use single quotes `'` for type `char` (like `'-'`) and double quotes `"` for `const char *` or `char *` (like: `"foobar"`)

Comment: For this code, the error message should be `but argument is of type 'char'`. Please always post code that actually matches your error messages, your output and/or your description.

Comment: Does your compiler show some warning about code that is not executed after `return`? The part `if(strcmp(op, "*")==0)` and all the following part inside that function will never be reached as you already return earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this error message

> expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char **'

does not correspond to the presented code because neither expression of the type `char **` is used in the program.

Also there is a logical error in the function due to the invalid placement of braces

```
int calc(int ran1,int ran2,char op){
    if(strcmp(op, "+")==0){
        return ran1+ran2;
    }

    if(strcmp(op, "-")==0){
        return ran1-ran2;
        if(strcmp(op, "*")==0){
            return ran1*ran2;
        }
        if(strcmp(op, "/")==0){
            return ran1/ran2;
        }
    }
}
```

Nevertheless for starters this initialization

```
char op="+";
```

is incorrect. It seems you mean

```
char op = '+';
```

That is you need to initialize the object `op` of the type `char` with the integer character constant `'+'` instead of the string literal `"+"`.

As the parameter `op` has the type char

```
int calc(int ran1,int ran2,char op){
```

then it may not be used in a call of `strcmp` like

```
 if(strcmp(op, "+")==0){
```

It is enough to use just the equality operator `==` in this and other similar if statements like

```
if ( op == '+' )
```

Take into account that instead of the if statements you could use a switch statement. For example

```
switch ( op )
{
case '+':
    //...
case '-':
    //...
}
```